# WebLogic in Docker: how to start managed servers automatically

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am learning Docker, and creating an image for Oracle WebLogic 12.2.1.4 server.

My image is ready, working fine. It contains

- an admin server
- two managed servers

When I run my image with `docker run -d -p 7001:7001 --name WL oracle/weblogic-12.2.1.4.0:1.0` the admin server starts automatically because I added the following line at the end of my `Dockerfile`:

```
CMD /u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/$DOMAIN_NAME/startWebLogic.sh
```

But I need to start managed servers manually. I need to login into the container and start them by hand:

1. `docker exec -it WL  /bin/bash`
2. `./startManagedWebLogic.sh MANAGED_SERVER_1 http://localhost:7001 &`
3. `./startManagedWebLogic.sh MANAGED_SERVER_2 http://localhost:7001 &`

This is not what I want. I want to start managed servers automatically after admin server is up and running.

I was thinking about to create a new bash script, copy it into the image and use it to boot up the admin and managed servers. Like this:

**start-wls-domain.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

/u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/$DOMAIN_NAME/startWebLogic.sh &

# there are a more sophisticated way to check the status of the admin server but it is okay for test
sleep 60

./startManagedWebLogic.sh MANAGED_SERVER_1 http://localhost:7001 &
./startManagedWebLogic.sh MANAGED_SERVER_2 http://localhost:7001 &
```

This script can be called from Dockerfile with `CMD` command.

But with this solution, I lost the ability to see the output on the default Docker log. The `docker logs WL -f` will display nothing.
Another issue with this bash script solution is if this script finished the container will stop running. Do I need an infinite loop at the end of this script?

If possible I would like to have a solution without `start-wls-domain.sh`.

What is the best and easiest way to start Weblogic managed servers automatically within a Docker container?

Comment: As a general rule you want to run one process per container.  That lets you see `docker logs` normally, and lets features like Docker's restart policy automatically take care of things when any single process fails.  I don't know how you'd translate that principle to WebLogic, though.

Comment: If I follow this principle than I need to create another image that contains only the managed server and then I need to start two instances from this image in order to I will have 2 managed servers in the WebLogic domain. It makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I followed the suggestions and I run different servers in different containers. That way I was able to start properly the server.

I published the solution on Github, [here](https://github.com/zappee/docker-images).